# Do we need to add 'a' for : I went to a tuition class on Monday?

Tags: grammar

Do we need to add 'a' for : I went to a tuition class on Monday?
I went to organ class on Monday.

Comment: It depends on what you're asking. *I went to class*, *I went to a class*, and *I went to the class* are all valid, but would be used under different circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

To me, "I went to organ class" suggests that organ class is an established thing that you're going to, perhaps regularly, while "I went to a tuition class" suggests that it's a new thing, or that you're going to a number of classes, and on that occasion it was the *tuition* class you went to.